# Determine rate of serial data frame transmission (via software)?

Tags: serial-port

I have a commercial device that outputs data in a 26-character string.
http://www.adamequipment.com/eu/pdf/1263.pdf

I can set-up the device to output data continuously, but I have no idea what its sampling frequency is. I have this setup with an 8N1 bit sequence.

I can change the baud rate, but that just affects transmission of bits within individual data frames.

I could try to look at the incoming stream on a scope to determine the rate, but I was wondering if there is a way in software to determine this.

Asking the same question in another way, I would like to find the time delta between [start] bits of adjacent frames to determine the frequency, as shown below.

......[start][b0][b1][b2][b3][b4][b5][b6][b7][stop]......[start][b0][b1][b2][b3][b4][b5][b6][b7][stop]......

Comment: The "received data ready" status/interrupt would indicate the rate you're looking for.  It's triggered off the stop bit(s) instead of the start bit, but they're separated by a fixed time interval, so it's the exact same rate.  FYI UARTs can/will typically transmit a message with *zero* delay between all char frames (unless you have very high-speed xmit and a slow/busy microcontroller and PIO instead of DMA).  Delays between messages is completely up to application software.

Comment: Usually (assuming the device can transmit as fast/faster than the serial data rate allows), if you increase the baud rate you will increase the overall data rate.  Feels like an XY problem - what is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Why do you need to determine the actual time between characters?

Comment: Good points, thank you.

I agree that I might not have asked the correct question.

My end-goal is to determine how often the 26-character (26 frame) packet is sent. Basically, how often the device is sampling the analog output and sending it to the PC.

The (26-character) ASCII string that is sent to the PC (containing the measurement I want) looks like this:

"+      5.22   g". There are a lot of CR/LF and space characters within the string.